# How do you bypass a FormClosing event in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

In my mdiMain, I have this code set.

```
Private Sub mdiMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = IIf(MsgBox("Closing this window will log you out. Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Log out?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes, False, True)
End Sub
```

My reason for this is to catch all triggers of closing the form. Either if the user clicks the log out button, or they press the x button on the top right corner of the window, or even if they press Alt-F4. Under the `FormClosed` of the same MDI, there is a set of instructions after it has been confirmed to log out. My problem is I also have a process where in the user is forcibly logged out of the program. Since the user is "forced" to log out, the confirmation dialog should be bypassed. But I'm not sure how to bypass the `FormClosing` event, and skip directly to the `FormClosed`.

So far I've only come up with one way and that is to set a boolean trigger. Something like

```
Private Sub mdiMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If ForceLogOut = True Then Exit Sub
    e.Cancel = IIf(MsgBox("Closing this window will log you out. Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Log out?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes, False, True)
End Sub
```

But for knowledge's sake, I would still like to hear from other people about other ways for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can check the [FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx) to see why the form is closing i.e. what event caused the form to close and set the cancel flag accordingly.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Select Case e.CloseReason
        Case CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing
            e.Cancel = False
        Case CloseReason.MdiFormClosing
            e.Cancel = If(MsgBox("Closing this window will log you out. Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Log out?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes, False, True)
            'etc
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note: You should use the `If`[Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) not the `IIf` function in VB.NET as it is type safe. You should also switch option strict on (which incidentally will not allow you to use `IIf` for this very reason)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll test it out as soon as i get home. The `CloseReason` is really interesting. I wonder if I can use form objects such as buttons? E.g. `CloseReason.btnClose` I have this addiction to one line codes like `IIf` But why is it not safe exactly?

Comment: No you can't, the close reason is an enum. Exlanation of each value is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @YinYangKim - The `If` _operator_ is superior to the `IIf` _function_ in that it is a true operator and it short circuits properly.  It will allow you to keep your 'addiction'.